# Rails: What is wrong with this logic of trying to render a parial on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, renderpartial

I'm trying to get the activities when the user clicks on a button called `display`
Controller:

```
 def display
    @activities =  Activity.all
    @activities = Activity.order("created_at desc")

    #we will need to find the Post id Through Users relation to the Comments
    #And this is because Activity Track, tracks Users actions, it breaks down from there.

    @posts = Post.all
    @user_comments = UserComment.all    
  respond_to do |format|               
    format.js { @activities = Activity.order("created_at desc") }
  end
```

View:

```
<%= link_to "Display", activities_path, :remote => true %>
<div id="notify" class="section-link">  
   </div>
```

display.js.erb

```
$('#notify').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'layouts/activity') %>");
```

_activity.html.erb

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
      <%= ActivityPresenter.new(activity, self).render_activity %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: @BillyChan it's now showing the content of the partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in display.js.erb:

`$('#notify').append('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'layouts/activity', :collection => @activities) %>');`

Then, try this in _activity.html.erb:

`<%= ActivityPresenter.new(activity, self).render_activity %>`

To ensure that whenever the user clicks on "Display' the `display` action is invoked, you will need to adjust your routes.rb file, which is located in the config directory.  You could do something like this in routes.rb:

`get '/activities/display', 'activities#display', as: :activity_display`

Once you make that change in routes.rb, you can edit your `link_to` like this:

`<%= link_to "Display", activity_display_path, :remote => true %>`

Comment: Okay, Progress :)! It says Ok 200 when I click on the button, but still nothing shows up!

Comment: I just edited my answer.  Try placing single quotation marks instead of double quotation marks around <%= escape_javascript(...) %>.

Comment: The Problem is that I have a different action, and the action is not brining back the display action!

Comment: What action are you using to invoke the display action?

Comment: So when the user clicks on the button, the different action is invoked and the display action is never called?  What is the source code of the other action?

Comment: So here is the scenario:
User clicks on `display` display hits    `<%= link_to "Display", activities_path, :remote => true %>` and the controller action is set default to `index` not `display`

Comment: Just modified my answer.  You'll need to make additions to your routes .rb file, located in the config directory.